# Quoting variables with the formula using `nest_`

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I am using the escape hatch version of the `tidyverse` functions with the formula interface and I have some issues when '-' is involved with `nest_`.

While this chunk works:

```
select_(mtcars, ~ -cyl)
```

Something similar doesn't work for `nest_`

```
nest_(mtcars, ~ -cyl)
```

> Error in x[[i]] <- value : invalid subscript type 'language'

Is there a way to make it works without writing all the remaining columns?

Comment: If you're using unquoted variable names, there's no reason to use the SE versions in the first place; just omit the `~`. Further, the tidyverse is in the middle of switching over to an [rlang](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/)-based SE system, on which it would be `mtcars %>% nest(-!!quo(cyl))` or with a string, `mtcars %>% nest(-!!rlang::sym('cyl'))`.

Comment: @alistaire I am using this for a wide project, not for an interactive session. As far as I understood in this case it should be better using SE. Am I wrong?

Comment: You only need SE if there is an input you don't control when writing the code, like if the user of a Shiny site can pick a grouping variable. Even so, only the functions that require it are usually changed to SE; if variables are fixed, there's no point.

Comment: This is pretty much my situation

Comment: [The dplyr programming vignette](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/programming.Rmd) is helpful for understanding how the new system works, if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you gave, you really don't need the standard-eval (SE) version; you could just use `nest` without the `~`:

```r
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% nest(-cyl)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl               data
#>   <dbl>             <list>
#> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 10]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>
```

If your real case is more complicated and does require SE, though, be aware that the tidyverse is in the process of switching to a [rlang](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/)-based NSE system, so the `*_` versions will be deprecated in favor of something like this:

```r
mtcars %>% nest(-!!rlang::quo(cyl))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl               data
#>   <dbl>             <list>
#> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 10]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>
```

or with strings,

```r
mtcars %>% nest(-!!rlang::sym('cyl'))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl               data
#>   <dbl>             <list>
#> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 10]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>
```

both of which work already if you install tidyr from GitHub. If you really want to get the old-style to work anyway, you can make it work equivalently like so:

```r
mtcars %>% nest_('data', names(.)[names(.) != 'cyl'])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl               data
#>   <dbl>             <list>
#> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 10]>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>
```